# Sort PHPDoc parameters in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm moving from SublimeText to PhpStorm, and I was wondering something :

In SublimeText, with the [PHPFMT](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/phpfmt) plugin activated, the PHPDoc I wrote was rearranged to match a certain pattern :

1. @see
2. @params
3. @throws
4. @return

For instance, if I write this PHPDoc :

```
/**
 * StackOverflow test
 *
 * @throws Exception
 * @param  string $param1
 * @return bool
 * @param  string $param2
 * @param  string $param3
 * @see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509189/sort-phpdoc-parameters-in-phpstorm
 */
```

It will be changed into this upon save :

```
/**
 * StackOverflow test
 *
 * @see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509189/sort-phpdoc-parameters-in-phpstorm
 *
 * @param  string      $param1
 * @param  string      $param2
 * @param  string      $param3
 * @throws Exception
 * @return bool
 */
```

Does PhpStorm provide something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible in current versions. The best IDE can do right now with PHPDoc is to add blank lines in few places and align text.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14694 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.